# Check if the integer value of an IP address is in a private range in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ip, postgresql-8.3

I am using MPP version of PostgreSQL that was forked off version 8.3

I have a large table  containing a column called ip_address which is inet and another column called hash_ip_address which bigint.  Every value in the hash_ip_address column is the converted value from the ip_address column using the hashinet function.  I am trying to use the integer values to determine when an address is private or public.  The problem I am having is I do not see a general way to check if the integer value of the IP address is private because some values are positive and some are negative like the example below:

```
select hashinet('10.10.0.1'::inet);
  hashinet
-------------
 -1939051471
(1 row)

select hashinet('10.0.0.4'::inet);
  hashinet
------------
 1510004552
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to determine if the an IP address is private using only the converted integer value form the hashinet function?

edit:  Here is the defintion of the hashinet function from http://doxygen.postgresql.org/network_8c.html#a0baabf8b98dbbcc39c6c1c814f9d86f8

Datum hashinet  (   PG_FUNCTION_ARGS         )

Definition at line 527 of file network.c.

References hash_any(), ip_addrsize(), PG_GETARG_INET_PP, and VARDATA_ANY.

```
{
    inet       *addr = PG_GETARG_INET_PP(0);
    int         addrsize = ip_addrsize(addr);

    /* XXX this assumes there are no pad bytes in the data structure */
    return hash_any((unsigned char *) VARDATA_ANY(addr), addrsize + 2);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition of that hashinet function? It's possible to just generate all of the private addresses and check against them but that's gonna be really slow.

Comment: Post the documentation for the hashinet function. If it is a real hash then there is no way to reverse it.

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL already have functions to manipulate IP addresses/subnets, see the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-net.html). Using the contains (`>>`) operator, you should be able to check if an ip address is in any of the 3 privateley defined subnets.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  You are using an internal PostgreSQL function that is not in the documentation.

It looks to me like hashinet calls hash_any() which is a true hash so there is no way to do this.

If you need the ints to be meaningful and useful outside of merely tying an arbitrary int to a IP address, a better approach would be to create your ip addresses to int by creating a new function:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION inet_to_int(inet) RETURNS INT language sql immutable AS 
 $$
 SELECT $1 - '0.0.0.0'::inet;
 $$;
```

Then use that.  From there your private ranges will correspond to int ranges and you can more easily check.

For example 10/8 addresses are `BETWEEN 167772160 AND 184549375`....